# Bind closure to class method

Tags: php, functional-programming, closures

I have functional and python background and now I am trying PHP.
I want to make something like this:

```
    <?php

class Test
{

    function __construct($func)
    {
        $this->build = $func;
    }


}

$test = new Test(function(){echo "neco";});
$test->build();

//my result
//Fatal error: Call to undefined method Test::build() in C:\Install\web\php\test.php on line 15


?>
```

But as you can see I am receiving error. Is there way to achieve class with method which depends on argument as closure in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing the magic function [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) in your `Test` class.

> [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an
>   object context.

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if($name === 'build') {
      $this->build();
    }
}
```

or, with `_call()`, and dynamic dispatch:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    call_user_func_array($this->{$name}, $arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke), just use it like this:

```
$test->build->__invoke();
```

output:

```
neco
```

Comment: I like this answer rather than @cristik's answer since it directly answers the question.

Comment: Actually I think mine works better, as the developer can simply write `$test->build()`, instead of an extra indirection level.

Comment: I agree. I am trying to have minimum code :) By the way, I had to improve your code like this


"return call_user_func_array($this->{$name}, $arguments);"

Or it is not returning  any value if I need it :)